# Compiling linux kernel: update-initramfs does not find new kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2

I try to compile a linux Kernel from sources, using the standard procedure

```bsh
make defconfig
make menuconfig
make -j9
make modules -j9
sudo make modules_install
sudo make install
```

My kernel is built successfully, however when doing `make install`, `update-initramfs` is not able to find the newly built kernel. Do you know what causes this error? I'm running on Debian 11

```bsh
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 5.16.0 \
    arch/x86/boot/bzImage System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 5.16.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.0
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 5.16.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.0
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.16.0
find: '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_XS5s90/lib/modules/5.16.0/kernel': No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 5.16.0 /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.0
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.0
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.16.0
```

Comment: I would probabley do `make -j9 all` rather than just `make -j9`.

Comment: @bib Make and make all does the same here, This is not the cause of my issue

Comment: Are you sure that error is just not a weird artifact that has no bearing on whether it actually worked? After all, it does appear to have created both vmlinuz & initrd. Since it is about modules, running `lsinitrd /boot/initrd.img-5.16.0` should tell you if it contains them.

Comment: No, this is a real error, and I'm not able to boot on my new kernel or it will drop me an busybox with a message `ALERT! UUID=d54[...] does not exist. Dropping to a shell !` Also, make clean'ing doesn't help.

Comment: Still run `lsinitrd /boot/initrd.img-5.16.0` though and check whether it has modules contained within it. The error given in the post does not directly relate to the error given in the comments. By the looks you may not have either built certain modules, or missed someother option. I would start by booting into a previous kernel, running `make mrproper && make oldconfig` in the 5.16.0 directory and try and boot that. If there are additional options, just take the defaults. FWIW, I went through a lot of pain trying to get the correct selection for a minimum kernel on a RPi.

Comment: The comment error suggests the correct device driver has not been built and loaded for the drive, which I assume is SATA or NVME.